# C++ copy constructor, destructor error and more

Tags: c++

I am really new to C++. I have tried to figure out how copy constructor works and also destructor, but I cant get it to work just wright.

I get two errors:

error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

delete [];

1. I have tried to put different things after delete [] but none of them worked, so I left it just blank at the moment.

class DynamicLine has no member named 'p2',

1. What am I doing wrong? I did decleare p2 in my test program.

This is my header file:

```
template<class T>
class DLine {

public:

DLine (T *v1, T *v2) 
    : v1 {v1},
    v2 {v2}
    {}


T* v1;
T* v2;

// Copy constructor
DLine(const DLine &l)
{
    v1 = l.v1;
    v2 = l.v2;
}


DLine& operator= (const DLine &l) {
if (this == &l) {
    return *this;
}
v1 = l.v1;
v2 = l.v2;

return *this;
}

~DLine()
{
delete [];
}

    };
```

I also have a vector class:

```
using namespace std;


Vector2::Vector2(float nx, float ny) 
    : x {nx}
    , y {ny}
{
}


float Vector2::distanceFrom(Vector2 v) {
    return sqrt( (x - v.x)*(x - v.x) + (y - v.y)*(y - v.y) ); 
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Vector2 v) {
    return os << "(" << v.x << "," << v.y << ")";
}
```

And this is part of my test program:

```
Vector2 p1 {3.0, 5.0}; 
Vector2 p2 {0,0}; 
Vector2 p3 {7.0, 8.0};
DLine<Vector2> l1 {&p1, &p2};   
DLine<Vector2> l2 {nullptr, nullptr};
l2 = l1;    
l2.p2 = &p3;
p1.x = 2.0;
```

Comment: Read a c++ book. That's my suggestion. You really need to understand what you are doing and I don't think you do.

Comment: @o_weisman: it is true that it is a basic question with relatively trivial answer, but instead of replying so, you could just explain the issue. That would be more productive, wouldn't it?

Comment: What do you suppose to delete with `delete[]`?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I don't think so. This site isn't about teaching beginners programming languages. So users shouldn't expect other people to just teach them everything. Especially if they haven't even taken the time to open a book or do some searching online for answers before taking up everyone's time with trivial questions. This is in my opinion disrespectful.

Comment: I understand about the destructor now, but what about the second problem. Is the error in copy constructor or somewhere else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @o_weisman Though your point might be correct, there are better ways to phrase it.

Comment: @o_weisman: please read this, and obey it: `Always be polite and have fun

It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil. There’s a real human being on the other end of that network connection, however misguided they may appear to be. We’re here to learn from our peers, not yell at each other.` from [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: @LaszloPapp How have I been uncivil? I suggested he/she read a book to get a decent starting point. Is this somehow offensive?

Comment: @o_weisman: "You do not know what you are doing, get a book" is everything, but productive, especially if the OP is maintaining a friendly tone with willingness to learn.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Let's agree to disagree

Comment: @LaszloPapp BTW, the last comment was not meant to be insulting, I really meant it. We're allowed our different opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `delete` is used to release the memory that's dynamically allocated.
2. `v1` and `v2` are the members of the class `Dline` and `p2` is just a variable you declared in the program.

Comment: Ok I understand about the delete. So if I just change p2 to v1 then it is correct, so there is no problem with constructors?

Comment: what problem are you talking?

Comment: In my test program I wanted use the line: l2.p2 = &p3;   to give l2 second point which would be p3. But it says: no member named p2. When I change p2 to v2 in there then it compiles, but I dont think it does what I tried to do.

Comment: you mean you want to assign `l2.v2' a new value? it doesn't conflict with the constructors

Comment: yes I want to assign new values. but if it doesn't conflict with them, then why can't I do it like that.

Comment: you can only use `l2.v2` or `l2.v1` because they are the member variables of `l2`,but `p2` is not

Answer (score 0):

You are not dynamically allocating memory... what are you trying to delete then...

You need not to delete all the pointers....`delete` operator is used to delete memory allocated using through `new` operator.

So here you can remove `delete` statement from destructor..

Answer (score 0):

At least you use incorrectly operator `delete[]` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/):

```
pt = new MyClass[3];
delete[] pt;
```